# Cor azul de fundo nos avatares das páginas de usuário

Tags: bug, novo-recurso, status-pronto, design

Notei que nas páginas do perfil do usuário e na listagem geral de usuários, é adicionado um fundo azul aos ícones (notar o meu, o do J. Bruni, Luis Cubal, por exemplo).

Provavelmente o correto seria branco, para que a transparência seja mostrada corretamente. Claro que a sombra dos perfis estendidos, que indica o mouseover, ficaria quadrada da mesma forma, mas aí seria opção minha de usar a tag para remover tal recurso para valorizar o ícone.

Na barra superior e nos outros lugares onde o ícone aparece, a transparência está sendo respeitada. Um problema desse tipo [já apareceu no Meta há muito tempo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101452/eeeek-gravatar-images-now-have-a-background-color-is-this-necessary), mas já foi resolvido, e no mesmo SOzão, os ícones aparecem com fundo branco:

**SOzão (correto, fundo "vazado")     x     SOpt (quadrado desnecessário)**

[image: comparativo dos ícones no SOpt e no SO]

**O problema também está na página de perfil do usuário:**

- No perfil de rede, fica certo: http://stackexchange.com/users/498517/bacco
- No SOzão, tudo em ordem também: https://stackoverflow.com/users/916193/bacco
- Em outros perfis de rede, como no https://superuser.com/users/52650/bacco , tudo ok.
- <s>Mas.. no SOpt eu "ganho" um quadrado desnecessário: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/</s>

**A pergunta (ou melhor, pedido):**

Podemos ter o fundo transparente (ou igual ao da página, que é o mesmo efeito) no SOpt, na página de usuários e no perfil do usuário, assim como ja é no resto da rede?

Update: vários usuários poderiam confundir a questão da sombra nos ícones com a questão do fundo transparente. Para evitar esta confusão, removi a sombra do meu ícone, para deixar claro que independente disto, <s>o problema persiste tanto na lista de usuários quanto no perfil</s>.

Update2: Aparenta resolvido, tanto no SOpt quanto no SOpt Meta.

Comment: Aqui é cinza background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231); mas isto não seria para destacar a área da imagem caso não houvesse nada? Até porque existe um shadow na div.

Comment: Acho que isso pode ser resolvido, porque realmente acaba alterando a imagem de alguns.

Comment: @Bacco Acredito que foi definitivo sim. Vou botar uma resposta aqui... (tinha esquecido!)

Comment: @Gabe Errei o nome da tag no comment anterior, é "status-pronto" :) Aliás, nesses casos o que é melhor? Remover a questão, ou deixar para "fins históricos e de documentação" caso reapareça problema do tipo?

Comment: @Bacco Deixar a questão. Não tem por que deletar. Ela fica aí pra referência futura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Jin deu uma olhada e resolveu o problema aqui. Ele acontecia por uma inconsistência no LESS, mas chamou nossa atenção pra algumas outras coisas esquisitas no HTML (o problema não acontecia com todos os usuários com avatar transparente, por exemplo).

Esse já foi consertado, mas se aparecer outra coisa... Só avisar

Answer (score 1):

Tem duas classes de CSS aqui, uma por fora com o `box-shadow` (que poderia ser mais claro, para combinar melhor com avatares de fundo branco), e uma classe interna, que define uma cor de fundo que aparece sob os avatares que têm transparência. Este screenshot mostra a classe de dentro (repare que tem dois *overrides* para `background-color`):

[image: screenshot do chrome inspector]

<sup>clique na imagem para ampliar</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi o fundo cinza `rgb(231, 231, 231)` é para fazer sentido ao avatar que tem shadow (indicando mais informações como bfavaretto comentou).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa sombra só aparece se você preencher o campo "about me" do perfil (aliás, sobrou em inglês isso). Ela indica que dá acesso a um popover com mais informações ao passar o mouse.

Comment: Esse fundo cinza existe unicamente por causa da sombra, ele mostra que existe um quadrado ali. Talvez escolheram  fazer isso para não ter borda no avatar. E realmente precisam traduzir o "about me"

Comment: Na lógica seria: 1- Sombra existe pra indicar mais info 2- fundo cinza existe para a sombra fazer sentido no quadrado

Comment: @bfavaretto pode ver que o brasofilo fica estranho com o fundo todo branco e uma sombra que não faz sentido em um fundo branco